# get html element value under another html tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

how can i get that label tag  `input type="text"` value?
This is not my code and the structure can't be altered

```
<div id="test">

    <label class="control input text">
        <span class="wrap">startdate</span>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="warning"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the label tag value"? Labels don't have values.

Comment: Now it's even more confusing. *"how can i get that label tag input type="text" value?"* is not a proper sentence. Do you want to get the value of the input element which is a child of that specific label element?

Comment: under label tag i have input type="text",i need that value?
i am up to this point
var item_children=document.getElementById("test");

alert(item_children);
var label_item=item_children.innerHTML;

Comment: You should edit the question instead of clarifying things just in comments. A question should be understandable without reading the comments (or answers).

Comment: @jasim do you have used this within any form? You want text box value or label value? where you want to get this value? If you answer these questions means any one can easily solve...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to support anything below IE8, you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to select that specific `input` element and then get its value via its [`.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties):

```
var value = document.querySelector('#test label.control input').value;
```

Comment: @jasim pick this answer as right answer. It may help to others.

Answer (score 1):

Just like that

```
var value = document.querySelector('#test .control input').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in jQuery

`var html = $('#test lable').html();`

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*. In addition to that, how is this suppose to work? You are not even passing a selector to jQuery.